# What was Student's (Gosset's) contribution in formulating the t-test?

Tags: distributions, t-test, history

A [recent question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51237/population-variance-and-sample-variance), [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54/why-do-us-and-uk-schools-teach-different-methods-of-calculating-the-standard-dev), and [cited source](https://maxwell.ict.griffith.edu.au/sso/biased_variance.pdf), recently made me aware that the $N-1$ correction for sample estimates of population variance is referred to as [Bessel's correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction).  Bessel was dead by 1846 ([wikipedia citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Bessel)) and the t-test was published in 1908 ([wikipedia citation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)).  For some reason, I had always assumed that the contribution of Gosset (aka Student) in formulating the t-test was the use of $N-1$ in the calculation of $s^2$.  Now it seems this contribution clearly belongs to Bessel.  In this vein, I ask what was Gosset's contribution in formulating the t-test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E. L. Lehmann addressed this question in an introduction to a reprint of Gosset's 1908 article in *Breakthroughs in Statistics, Volume II--Methodology and Distribution* (Samuel Kotz & Norman L. Johnson, eds., 1992).

Lehmann first describes the state of the art in Gosset's time: it amounted to a "z test" where the estimated standard deviation was treated as if it were a constant.  Then he discusses Gosset's contribution:

> However, if the sample size $n$ is small, $S^2$ will be subject to considerable variation.  It was the effect of this variation that concerned Student, the pseudonym of W. S. Gosset... .  He pointed out that if the form of the distribution of the $X$'s is known, this variation can be taken into account, since for any given $n$ the distribution of $t$ is then determined exactly.  He proposed to work out this distribution for the case in which the $X$'s are normal.

This in fact is what Gosset did, albeit without mathematical rigor: he derived some properties of the distribution of $t$ for the normal case, matched them to properties of known distributions, and correctly guessed its distribution--acknowledging that this was less than rigorous.  To support his guess, he conducted a Monte-Carlo simulation using samples of four from a dataset.

Gosset wrote pseudonymously because his employer (the Guinness brewery) apparently felt that this improved understanding of small-sample variation was a bit of an advantage in the business : it would have led to improved quality control procedures.

Comment: Thank you. My answer got chopped up it seems. Besides, yours is better in nearly all respects.

Comment: Monte Carlo in 1908 - men were men in those days...

Comment: @Corone That is very observant: he probably carried out all calculations with pencil and paper.